# Passing values from a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

1. Do I need to create a `getCurrent` to keep bindings (if I have `{{current.status}}` in my view ex)? Or would `current: current` be enough?
2. Would I loose the binding to `status` if Id do `$scope.status = services.status`. Meaning `status` wont be updated in a view if its changed.
3. Will bindings to `someValue` be kept? Meaning it will change in my view if its changed in the service if I do `$scope.someValue = services.someValue`

   ```
   function someService() {
   var current = {
       status: ''
   };

   var someValue = 'hello';

   //////////

   var service = {
       current: current,
       getCurrent: getCurrent,
       status: current.status,
       someValue: someValue
   };

   return service;

   //////////

   function getCurrent() {
       return current;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: What problems you are actually facing ?

Comment: none, Im just trying to understand how things work :D

Comment: service is working as constructor, if want to use function or variable within another service's function or variable, then you can be able to do that by simply using `this` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you don't need the getCurrent method, current:current should be enough.

2 & 3. No, because you are setting the scope variables to the service's properties ($scope.status = service.status) and those properties are strings, the bindings will NOT be kept. However, if you instead assign the entire service object as the scope variable and use dot notation in your bindings, then they will because you will be updating the object whose reference was injected into the controller (the service). The important things to note are in order to understand why your method does not work, but the alternative does is to understand that

- objects are passed by reference
- for the above reason, angular recommends that your bindings always use dot notation.

This is what your code would could look like to make it work:

```
//service
.factory('service', function() {
    var current = {
      status: 'theStatus'
    };

    var someValue = 'hello';

    var service = {
        current: current,
        status: current.status,
        someValue: someValue
    };

    return service;
  })

// controller
.controller('theCtrl', ['$scope', 'service', function($scope, service) {
  $scope.serviceData = service;
}])

// view
<p>{{serviceData.current}}</p>
<p>{{serviceData.status}}</p>
<p>{{serviceData.someValue }}</p>
```

And here is the sample plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/n2P07mjwnMVHCl4l7SAj?p=preview . Note that it has 2 examples, the first one shows your method and the second one shows the object method.

EDIT - BIG CAVEAT:

One big caveat to notice is that in your service, if the `someValue` or the `current` variables change, your view will NOT be updated. Because we are returning the service object, changes WILL reflect in the service object's `someValue`, `current` and `status` properties, but those WILL NOT cause the original `current` and `someValue` variables to also be in sync.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as you are programming in JavaScript, you're not obliged to use getter/setter as you would in Java for example.

All angular service are **singleton**, so you can easily share some data. Moreover by creating **Factory**, you'll be able to return an **object**, with want you want inside, for example method, that will be **invoked**. You can make the connection with the **factory pattern**.

In your case, you can save your service instance into your current `$scope`.

**EDIT**

In your factory, you should return your `current` object. Then, you should use it in your view to retrieve current status. So, you will get an **object**, not just a fixed value, so it will updated.

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, Service) {

  //Register the Service instance into our scope
  $scope.service = Service;

  //Retrieve current object with status property
  $scope.working = Service.current;

  //Retrieve VALUE of current object
  $scope.not_working = Service.status;

  $scope.changeStatus = function() {
    Service.changeStatus('another status');
  }

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**Service**

```
(function(){

  function Service($timeout) {

    var current = {
      status: 'off'
    };

    var someValue = 'hello';

    $timeout(function() {
      //Update service status
      current.status = 'on';
    }, 500);

    //////////

    var service = {
      //Return the current object
      current: current,
      //Just set the VALUE of current.status
      status: current.status,
      getCurrent: getCurrent,
      someValue: someValue,
      changeStatus: changeStatus
    };

    return service;

    function getCurrent() {
      return current;
    }

    function changeStatus(status) {
      alert("status changed");
      //Modifying status property of current object
      current.status = status;
    }

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Service', Service);

})();
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>

    Status : {{working.status}}<br>

    Status not updating : {{not_working}}<br>

    SomeValue : {{service.someValue}}
    <br>
    <button ng-click="changeStatus()">go</button>

  </body>
```

You can see the [**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ieqLhQSn9ngCBlzwEVkb?p=preview)

Comment: Your code wont work if you change the status from another service see here http://plnkr.co/edit/oR2aHI?p=preview. It kind of explains my question though :P

Comment: No it works, but you've done a little mistake. In your factory, you are retrieving the **value** of your status. You have to access by the **object property**. See the [**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ieqLhQSn9ngCBlzwEVkb?p=preview)

Comment: Yes I see what you mean now! I think you cleared some things up in my head. Thank you Paul!

Answer (score 0):

Angular will keep track of changes on $scope with it's implementation of dirty checking. So, when an event occurs within your Angular application and an $apply or $digest is invoked, Angular will iterate through all of the $watch values and update any bound values accordingly.

Without the newer controllerAs syntax, you would want to put any values that you want bound onto the $scope object. Then, any events fired within your Angular application will trigger your updates automatically.

Here is a simple demo binding $scope.status.value to three DOM references:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdKrqe

To answer your questions directly:

1. No, you don't need to create getters/setters for your bound values due to Angular dirty checking. But, current: current is not enough. That would be reassigning a value outside of Angular to its $scope and depending on the Object type, this will be assigned by either value or reference.  Any 'connection' to the original value will be lost when you assign by value (Numbers, Strings, Booleans...)
2. Yes, you would loose your binding if service.service is assigned by value i.e. You wouldn't be able to update services.status to update the value of $scope.status.  If you changed it a bit to: `$scope.services = services;` Then $scope.services.status would be bound.
3. If you used the suggestion from above, any changes would be reflected in your original object: `$scope.services = services;` then, any changes on services. would be reflected in your original object.

I think the two main points here are understanding assignment by value/reference in JS and how Angular implements bound values by dirty checking.